# Postgres server is running locally but refusing connection

Tags: sql, postgresql

After installing postgres and pgAdmin 4 on Ubuntu 22.04 I want to setup a server listening on localhost.

The pg service is running

[image]

but when trying to create a new server I get the following error

[image]

I think the terminal error points to the same problem

[image]

I think the server is running locally but what am I missing / how can I accept the missing socket connections?

Comment: Check the database server's logfile.  In my experience `service ... status` is rarely helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Could you check if the listen_addresses in the postgresql.conf accepts connections from localhost or set it to '*', if no special restriction required

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not able to find that file... Based on this https://linuxconfig.org/ubuntu-22-04-postgresql-installation it should be at `/etc/postgresql/<version>/main/postgresql.conf` but I can only find a `postgresql-common` inside `etc` which does not contain the file

Comment: You can run "ps -ef|grep postgres" and look for a path following the "-D" option. The postgres.conf should be located in that directory